# htaccess 301 redirecting of subdomain - home page issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I needed to 301 redirect my subdomain URL to the Directory structure URL.

So blogs.mydomain.com should be redirected to www.mydomain.com/blog/ and below is the .htaccess that is changed.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blogs.sampledomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sampledomain.com/blog/$1 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

It works fine and the blogs part is taken care. But, when I try to go to www.sampledomain.com it takes me to www.sampledomain.com/blog.

With this I am not able to land onto the homepage at all.

Comment: This rule is only executing for `blog` subdomain so it won't impact `www.sampledomain.com`.